# How to Assign Elastic IP to Elastic Beanstalk Environment with NLB (for inbound traffic)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

When Elastic Beanstalk auto-generates resources, NLB is created with Network mapping for subnets with "Assigned by AWS" IPv4 addresses.
How it would be possible to a associate Elastic IP to Beanstalk environment with Network Load Balancer for **inbound traffic**? *(This is not to be confused with [static "source" IP address](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-static-IP-address) in Beanstalk)*

I reviewed [related CloudFormation resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-subnetmapping.html) to see if or how I can make use of them but I am not sure if this can be applicable for Elastic Beanstalk environments.

Comment: Why would you need EIP if you have NLB?

Comment: @Marcin you can attach an EIP to an NLB. You have to do that if you want to ensure the public IP doesn't change between delete/recreate of the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: What is the use case for inbound ip to not change? Outbound would make sense if the app communicates to other ip whitelisted apps over the internet. Why not make a dns record in route53 which is an A type and aliases towards elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Some users require static IP so that they can add it to their corporate(?) firewall as an "allowed" destination.

Comment: Well that sucks. I think a DNS record would be alot better for that use case, if you do ever need to change IP adresses, you now have bunch of user who added it directly to their firewall; I learnt that the hard way with letting users adding our IP directly to their SPF record; switching e-mail providers after that was a real pain. @pars

Answer (score 2):

From the page you linked in your question:

> AllocationId
>
> [Network Load Balancers] The allocation ID of the Elastic IP address for an internet-facing load balancer.

You need to pass the `AllocationId` of your Elastic IP. The `AllocationId` is one of the return values of the [CloudFormation Elastic IP resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-eip.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to give this a try.